# Permission denied issues with Amazon EC2 and S3 hosting

Tags: amazon-ec2, lamp, web-hosting

I hired a freelancer to develop a PHP CI application hosted on Amazon EC2, and the app doesn't work. I am using Wowza with EC2 and S3. I have been seeing permission denied problems. I have Ubuntu and I'm trying to install a LAMP server and run public DNS on the instance. I have set up SSH as well.

I found the elastic IP of the instance we are running and used GoDaddy domain manager. I thought that simply pointing the domain to the instance would work. Do I have to change the nameservers on GoDaddy's side as well? Where would I find the right ones?

I have very little server-side understanding. I'm sure the solution is just a simple change, something like one line of code, a different user name or a different ID number. What do I need to do?

Comment: Permission denied problems generally have nothing to do with DNS.  Can you be a little more specific about what your problem is?  When you try to connect to your web site via the domain name, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

you should point your domain to your elastic ip of your EC2 instance. This should be done from where you host your DNS server. If you don't have one, you can change the settings inside the godaddy account to point to your DNS service.